# Соединить DataGrid с List

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq

После LINQ-запроса пытаюсь соединить ответ с DataGrid:

```
context = new cokoEntities4();
s = new List<string>();
var itemList = from SchoolName in context.View_1 select SchoolName;

foreach (var item in itemList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.SchoolName);
    s.Add(item.SchoolName);

}
dg.ItemsSource = s;
```

Вот что он мне показывает:

[image]

Хотя в консоль выводить все правильно:

```
ГБОУ «Гимназия № 12»
ГБОУ «Гимназия № 14»
ГБОУ «Общеобразовательная школа-интернат № 1»
ГБОУ «Общеобразовательная школа-интернат для детей-сирот и детей, оставшихся без попечения родителей № 2»
ГБОУ «Президентский лицей»
```

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGrid заполняется с помощью свойств в объектах, у типа String такое свойство одно, это Lenght, который и выдается. Используйте объекты с явными свойствами, чтобы такого не было, к примеру:

```
class Institution{
    public String Title { get; set; }
};
List<Institution> list = new List<Institution>();

/*******                    ********/

var itemList = from SchoolName in context.View_1 select new Institution(){Title = SchoolName};

foreach (var item in itemList)
{
    list.Add(item);
}
dg.ItemsSource = list;
```

Comment: Компилятор выдает ошибку в районе:@Alex Krass, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора. ' select new Institution()
                               {
                                   Title = SchoolName.ToString()
                               };'

Comment: @derkode, если говорите об ошибке, то приводите и ее текст сразу.